# Unmarshalling time.Time changes the response

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm getting some data from a server and Un-Marshalling the JSON. When I cast the datetime string to a string, I get all my results as an Un-Marshalled object, but when I type it as `time.Time`, the rest of the object is cut short. Also, the date is wrong, which might be a hint.

I started casting the time to a string:

```
type History struct {
    Id      string
    Created string
    Items   []HistoryItem
}

    var response []History
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &response)
```

Which is great, I get back a list like this:

```
[{91096 2021-06-04T10:28:21.179-0400 [{Rank  Ranked higher}]} {91078 2021-06-04T09:49:28.630-0400 [{Target end  8/Jun/21}]} //...etc
```

But when I try to cast it as `Time`:

```
type History struct {
    Id      string
    Created time.Time
    Items   []HistoryItem
}
```

I get a single item and it's clearly the wrong time. No other values in that object either.

```
[{91096 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC []}]
```

The actual JSON representations look like this:

```
"created": "2021-06-04T10:28:21.179-0400",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time "2021-06-04T10:28:21.179-0400" is not in a recognized format. You have to parse it yourself. You can use this format to parse it:

```
t, err:=time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999-0700","2021-06-04T10:28:21.179-0400")
```